# How to compare 2 HTML strings

Tags: c#, html, string, compare

How can I compare 2 html strings for equality? I was trying some 'stuff' out with the Agility pack, but it doesn't have a compare method, or anything like that.

For the record, the .NET framework doesn't do the trick.

[EDIT]

With comparing 2 html strings, I mean the `innerHTML` of a webpage.

[/EDIT]

Example:

For example, press right mouse button on this page, and click 'view page source' (i use firefox). Put that content to a `string` variable.

Now do this again, exactly like you did before but pick another page and create a new `string` variable.

When you're done, compare those 2 `strings` against each other.

Comment: What do you mean by _"compare 2 HTML strings"_ ? How do you want to compare between them?

Comment: What is equality criteria for such strings? Please provide an example

Comment: A string is a string, why does it matter if it contains HTML? I think you need to give more details on what you really want to compare...

Comment: please provide more details...

Comment: again post an example...

Comment: There is your precious example, Robin

Comment: @Thomas, unfortunately, the .NET Framework disagrees with you. A simple stringA.Equal(stringB) just doesn't return true. It never is 'equal'. This also goes for Compare, CompareTo, etc. I've tried them all.

Comment: Are you trying to determine the difference between two web pages?

Comment: @Ferruccio, one can put it that way, yes.

Comment: @Yustme, if it returns false, then the strings *are* different... perhaps the bits of HTML are semantically equivalent, but with different formatting, whitespace, etc. String.Equals isn't broken...

Comment: Suppose you're right, how can I 'over come' this little inconvenience?

Answer (score 1):

It's all going to the point if you're actually comparing valid XML.

HTML is a derivate language from XML, and if both `string`'s are valid XML you can always create two `XMLDocument`'s and compare them equally.

If there's a problem with your HTML syntax, then you need other algorithm for the comparation, like stripping all double spaces, strip all spaces between tags, and compare them ...

of course you will need to workout the correct representation as `<body style="padding:2em;color:white;">` is exactly the same as `<body style="color:white;padding:2em">` as sake of HTML...

Comment: The website isn't mine, so even if its not well formed, there is nothing i can do about it. However, i'm very interested in your solution in your 3rd paragraph. Would string.Trim() do the trick?

Comment: XHTML may be based on XML, but HTML is based on SGML. You can have valid HTML that is not valid XML and can't be processed by an XML parser.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're only interested in the textual content of the HTML elements (i.e. the stuff between ) then just compare the .InnerText properties of the two elements - this returns a string containing all of the concatenation of all the "#text" nodes of all child nodes.

Comment: Hi, it's actually about the entire html page. Everything in it. including the tags etc.